# peewee - Define models separately from Database() initialization

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, orm, peewee

I need to use some ORM engine, like **peewee**, for handling SQLite database within my python application. However, most of such libraries offer syntax like this to define `models.py`:

```
import peewee

db = peewee.Database('hello.sqlite')

class Person(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

However, in my application, i cannot use such syntax since database file name is provided by outside code after import, from module, which imports my `models.py`.

How to initialize models from outside of their definition knowing dynamic database file name? Ideally, `models.py` should not contain "database" mentions at all, like normal ORM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are looking at proxy feature :
[proxy - peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database)

```
database_proxy = Proxy()  # Create a proxy for our db.

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy  # Use proxy for our DB.

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()

# Based on configuration, use a different database.
if app.config['DEBUG']:
    database = SqliteDatabase('local.db')
elif app.config['TESTING']:
    database = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
else:
    database = PostgresqlDatabase('mega_production_db')

# Configure our proxy to use the db we specified in config.
database_proxy.initialize(database)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the answer!