# How to manage a peewee database in a separate module?

Tags: python, database, peewee

I want to have my database implementation in a separate module or class. But I am struggling with a few details. A simple example:

```py
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

db.connect()
db.create_tables([User,])
db.commit()

@db.atomic()
def add_user(name):
    User.create(name=name).save()

@db.atomic()
def get_user(name):
    return User.get(User.name == name)
```

So far this is working fine. I can implement my interface to the database here and import this as a module.

Now I want to be able to choose the database file at runtime. So I need a way to define the Model classes without defining `SqliteDatabase('somefile')` before. I tried to encapsulate everything in a new Database class, which I can later import and create an instance from:

```
from peewee import *

class Database:

    def __init__(self, dbfile):
        self.db = SqliteDatabase(dbfile)

        class BaseModel(Model):
            class Meta:
                database = self.db

        class User(BaseModel):
            name = CharField()

        self.User = User

        self.db.connect()
        self.db.create_tables([User,])
        self.db.commit()

    @self.db.atomic()    # Error as self is not known on this level
    def add_user(self, name):
        self.User.create(name=name).save()

    @self.db.atomic()    # Error as self is not known on this level
    def get_user(self, name):
        return self.User.get(self.User.name == name)
```

Now I can call for example `database = Database('database.db')` or choose any other file name. I can even use multiple database instance in the same program, each with its own file.

However, there are two problems with this approach:

- I still need to specify the database driver (`SqliteDatabase`) before defining the Model classes. To solve this I define the Model classes within the `__init__()` method, and then create an alias to with `self.User = User`. I don't really like this approach (it just doesn't feel like neat code), but at least it works.
- I cannot use the `@db.atomic()` decorator since `self` is not known at class level, I would an instance here.

So this class approach does not seem to work very well. Is there some better way to define the Model classes without having to choose where you want to store your database first?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to change database driver at the runtime, then [Proxy](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database) is a way to go

```
# database.py
import peewee as pw

proxy = pw.Proxy()

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
  class Meta:
    database = proxy

class User(BaseModel):
  name = pw.CharField()

def add_user(name):
  with proxy.atomic() as txn:
    User.create(name=name).save()

def get_user(name):
  with proxy.atomic() as txn:
    return User.get(User.name == name)
```

From now on each time you load the module, it won't need a database to be initialized. Instead, you can initialize it at the runtime and switch between multiple as follows

```
# main.py

import peewee as pw
import database as db

sqlite_1 = pw.SqliteDatabase('sqlite_1.db')
sqlite_2 = pw.PostgresqlDatabase('sqlite_2.db')

db.proxy.initialize(sqlite_1)
sqlite_1.create_tables([db.User], safe=True)
db.add_user(name="Tom")

db.proxy.initialize(sqlite_2)
sqlite_2.create_tables([db.User], safe=True)
db.add_user(name="Jerry")
```

But if the connection is the only thing that matters, then [`init()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration) method will be enough.

Comment: Wow, that is actually documented, why did I miss that? The documentation also recommends using `[db.init()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#deferring-initialization)` if the database driver does not vary.

Comment: @Feodoran Thanks for addition. Updated the answer.

Comment: just wanted to add a direct link to the documentation on [how to dinamically define a database](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html?highlight=proxy#dynamically-defining-a-database)

Comment: I think db connection created using Proxy class needs to be closed explicitly .

Comment: `db.init` can be used to change connection details of one database type, e.g. `PostgresSQLDatabase` or `SqliteDatabase`. 

Proxies need to be used, when you want to use different database types, e.g. psql for production and sqlite for local testing

Comment: Just for a reminder: peewee (v3.11, at present) replace the `Proxy` with [DeferredThroughModel](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#DeferredThroughModel) for this usage.

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration

Comment: why proxy.atomic() ?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to be able to choose the database file at runtime. So I
>   need a way to define the Model classes without defining
>   SqliteDatabase('somefile') before. I tried to encapsulate everything
>   in a new Database class, which I can later import and create an
>   instance from

Peewee uses the meta class to define the name of the table (`Model.Meta.db_table`) and database( `Model.Meta.database`)

set these attribute before calling a Model specific code ( either to create a table or to DML statements)

['Allow to define database dynamically'](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/221#issuecomment-203216707)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I cannot use the @db.atomic() decorator since self is not known at class level

Do it, as you do it with `self.User`.
I wonder about `atomic()` instead of `atomic`, but you tell *is working fine*.

```
class Database:

    def __init__(self, dbfile):
        self.db = SqliteDatabase(dbfile)

        ...
        @self.db.atomic()
        def __add_user(self, name):
            self.User.create(name=name).save()
        self.add_user = __add_user

        @self.db.atomic()
        def __get_user(self, name):
            return self.User.get(self.User.name == name)
        self.get_user = __get_user
```

Related: [Define models separately from Database() initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395528/peewee-define-models-separately-from-database-initialization)